# Flex Create an array of images to insert into a itemRenderer

Tags: arrays, apache-flex, image

I am trying to loop through a list of images and then add them to list box with a itemRenderer

```
public function createDataProvider():ArrayList
{

    var a:Array = new Array();
    for (var i:int = 0; i < select_query.data.length; i++){
        var x:Image = new Image(); 
        x.height = 95
        x.width = 126
        x.id = "list_image_" + i
        x.source = (PathToMyImage); 

         a[i] = x


    }
    return new ArrayList(a);
}
<s:List id="myListX" width="234" height="550"
        dragEnabled="true" dropEnabled="true" dragMoveEnabled="true"
        dataProvider="{createDataProvider()}">
    <s:layout>
    <s:TileLayout id="myListX_tiles" 
                  requestedRowCount="1"
                  horizontalGap="0"
                  verticalGap="0" horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle" />
    </s:layout> 
        <s:itemRenderer>

        </s:itemRenderer>        
</s:List>
```

Comment: You need to ask us a question for us to answer it. You're sort of on the right track, you don't create the image in your loop, let the itemRenderer create the image based on the data.

Comment: Can you show me how to create the image in the itemRenderer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
public function createDataProvider():ArrayList
{

    var a:Array = new Array();
    for (var i:int = 0; i < select_query.data.length; i++){
         a[i] =  (PathToMyImage); 
    }
    return new ArrayList(a);
}

<s:List id="myListX" width="234" height="550"
        dragEnabled="true" dropEnabled="true" dragMoveEnabled="true"
        dataProvider="{createDataProvider()}">
    <s:layout>
    <s:TileLayout id="myListX_tiles" 
                  requestedRowCount="1"
                  horizontalGap="0"
                  verticalGap="0" horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle" />
    </s:layout> 
    <s:itemRenderer>
        <fx:Component>
            <s:DataRenderer>
                <s:Image source="{data}" height="95" width="126" />
            </s:DataRenderer>
        </fx:Component>
    </s:itemRenderer>

</s:List>
```

Comment: don't forget to accept this as an answer if it helps. It's good for your reputation too.